# information_schema.columns command not working in DBeaver

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I am trying to determine if there is an issue with the following script itself, or if the issue is within the DBeaver tool I am forced to use at work.

Here is the SQL script (I've tried variations as well):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'schemaname';
```

The ultimate goal is to run a query that returns all the columns for all tables in a database in one exportable table.  From all the searches I've done, it seems that DBeaver does not like the information_schema.columns part of the script, so I'm trying to determine if that is the case, or if there is an alternate version of that script, or if this is a DBeaver bug.  The query has worked successfully in other tools like SQLserver.

I am using DBeaver 4.2.0.

Comment: Do you know your database/vendor?(I imply mysql!) what means "doesnt like the ... part"? (error message?)

Comment: The database is an internal database. I cannot paste the exact error as I"m posting from my personal laptop and not my work laptop, but the error in DBeaver is: 
Query Execution failed
Reason: SQL Error [10001] [42S02]: Error while compiling statement: SEmanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'columns'.

In any query I run including the information_schema.columns line I get an error in DBeaver (not another SQLserver).

Comment: the query that you want/need, is db specific... "internal" is no big help ... i think dbeaver is not to blame.

Comment: ...can you "browse" `information_schema` ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "browse" information_schema?  DBeaver may not be to blame, but I know that query works in another tool in the same db (me and a colleague have tried many different db's and result is the same).  What else could the problem be related to?

Comment: To further clarify, previous to this query, I have selected the DB so it is active and I'm able to show tables for example: SHOW TABLES FROM dbname

Comment: I have also tried this variation of the query:
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()

Comment: by "browse" i mean ... in the "Database Navigator" (tab)